# AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'object'

Tags: object

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'object'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Bmtn.png)

I tried reinstall numpy, and importing numpy with path

Answer (score 2):

`numpy.object` was deprecated in [version 1.20.0](https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations). You can use `np.object_` instead.

From your screenshot, it looks like it is `tensorflow` which is referencing `np.object`; in this case you should either update tensorflow to a newer version that is compatible with numpy 1.20, or downgrade numpy to version 1.19 or older so it works with your tensorflow installation.

Answer (score 1):

this solves the issue for me:

```
np.object = np.object_
```

to be honest i don't understand what this doing in the background, so be carful but it seemed to work.